# Confused about Ryanair cabin bag policy

Tags: luggage, hand-luggage, ryanair

Here's a quote from the [Ryanair website](https://www.ryanair.com/ie/en/useful-info/help-centre/faq-overview?cmpid=email_AT_Advisory_3W2WAdvisory_en_noseg_noab_nodev_dl_activetrip#2-1):

> **What you CAN bring on board**
>
> - All passengers are entitled to bring 1 small personal bag on board which must fit under the seat in front of you (35cm x 20cm x 20cm). Examples include, handbag, laptop bag and small back pack.
> - Passengers who have purchased "Priority & 2 Cabin Bags" or Plus/Flexi/Family ticket or connecting flight ticket can bring 1 additional 10kg bag on board which must fit into the baggage sizer (not exceeding 10kg and dimensions 55cm x 40cm x 20cm).
> - **Passengers who choose not to purchase ”Priority & 2 Cabin Bags” and arrive at the gate with 2 bags, your second larger bag (10kg weight Dimensions: 55cm x 40cm x 20cm) will be taken off you, tagged and placed in the aircraft hold free of charge**. Please ensure all valuables are removed. You will collect this bag at the baggage belt at your destination airport. (N.B. Remember to bring your passport with you if you need to go through passport control at your destination airport.)

We are 2 adults and 2 children. In addition to the 4 tickets, we purchased two "priority & 2 Cabin Bags". I thought it meant we could bring 4 small bags (35cm x 20cm x 20xm) + 2 medium bags (10kg, 55cm X 40cm x 20cm).

But then I saw the highlighted section above, which seems to indicate we didn't have to pay for "Priority & 2 Cabin Bags", and we can bring 4 medium bags free of charge.

So does the extra fee for "Priority & 2 Cabin Bags" only give us the right to have the medium bags with us in the cabin (as opposed to checking them at the gate)?

Another small concern is about packing sharp objects (such as shaving razor) and liquids in larger containers. I usually pack them in my checked baggage, but this time I didn't purchase checked baggage. These items are usually not allowed to pass through security. So if I don't check in any bags (prior to security), does it mean I can't pack a razor and liquid containers larger than 100ml? Or can I still pack them in a bag that I'll check at the gate?

Comment: Safety razors are fine. Straight razors are not. The 100mL limit is generally airport -- not airline -- policy, so repackage your large bottles into a series of 100mL ones.

Comment: I thought this baggage allowance policy only comes out in November 2018? I am flying October 2018 and k booked these flights in March, yet I keep getting messages to tell me to buy priority boarding????? Last time I fly with these scam artists!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### As of November 2018, this answer is outdated. [See this answer instead](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/117391/how-does-the-new-ryanair-luggage-policy-work/117394#117394).

Feeling confused is natural. Ryanair's extras are designed to confuse.

Yes, buying "Priority & 2 cabin bags" does not change your baggage allowance, it only changes in what part of the aircraft the bags will be transported. If you do not pay this fee, you are allowed to bring your small bag on to the aircraft, while you will leave your larger bag in a pile outside the aircraft, and it will be placed in the hold. You will then need to collect it from baggage claim. Paying the fee enables you to bring the small bag and the larger bag into the aircraft.

Since you have four tickets and have paid two "Priority & 2 cabin bags" fees, you will be able to bring four small bags and two larger bags into the cabin, and you can gate-check two larger bags.

The same security rules apply to the gate-checked larger bags as would apply to carry-on luggage, since you will be bringing the bags through security and to the gate yourself.

Comment: Note, that it's going to change starting 1st Nov 2018 - see https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/help-centre/faq-overview/Baggage#0-0