# Ryanair visa checks

Tags: visas, airports, airport-transfer, connecting-flights, ryanair

I'm going to travel to Amsterdam tomorrow with Ryanair. I'm from Thailand and studying in the UK. So I have my UK student visa and a Schengen visa, which I got from Thailand to travel to the Netherlands. However, I just checked-in online with Ryanair an hour ago and it said that I need to have my visa checked before going to security.

My flight is Newcastle to Dublin and Dublin to Amsterdam. When I was booking this, I booked it separately, as Ryanair doesn't fly from Newcastle to Amsterdam directly. But the flight is on the same day, with a 3-hour layover (as I thought it could be like a connecting flight). Moreover, I have looked at travel agents (Opodo and Skyscanner) for Ryanair, the booked tickets are separate as well.

So now I'm afraid that I won't be able to board tomorrow as I don't have an Irish visa.

Comment: There's a question hiding in there somewhere, but what is it?

Comment: How much does it cost (in money and time) to get to the Newcastle airport?  If it's not very much, the best way to find out whether you'll be allowed to board is to show up at the airport and try to board.

Comment: @phoog not so much just about 5 quids for round trips.

Comment: How did it work out?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you hold a Thai passport and no other nationality, you can transit without a visa **as long as you do not change terminals OR have checked baggage**.

Your flight details should tell you what terminal your flights land/depart from, and whether they are different.

The second bit on no checked bags also [applies to gate-checked bags for larger items of luggage](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/117391/108), which it will in most cases. The only way to avoid having this gate-checked (and therefore forced to go through border control to baggage claim) will be to buy Priority Boarding.

This is [from INIS](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/visa-required-transit):

> You do not need a transit visa*
>
> - You do not need a transit visa, subject to the information below, to travel through an Irish airport/seaport on your way to another
>     destination. When travelling
>
> To transit through Ireland means you are only passing through an Irish
>   airport or seaport to travel to another destination. **To transit, you
>   cannot pass through border control. If you pass through border
>   control, you are not transiting**.
>
> As you are visa required to travel to Ireland but your nationality is
>   not listed on the transit visa required list, you must check with your
>   airline to see if you have to pass through border control.
>
> If you have to pass through border control, you need a short stay or
>   long stay visa to travel to Ireland. When do I pass through border
>   control?
>
> Times you would pass through border control would include, but are not
>   limited to:
>
> - **Leaving the terminal building for any purpose, including in some cases having to transfer between terminals for a connecting flight.**
> - **In cases where you must collect your bags and check them in to your onward flight.**
> - **Transiting overnight - all Irish airports close at night and passengers are required to pass through border control.**
>
> Before you travel please check with your Airline if you have to pass
>   through border control.

Comment: Thank you @Ankur I don't have any check-in bags. However, as the flight is not a connecting flight (even though I thought it is) but it is at the same day but 3 hours layover. I don't know if Ryanair would let me board as I don't have Irish Visa.

Comment: @Jazz Check that the flights are in the same terminal and then take a printout of what the Irish INIS says

Comment: As I understand it, passengers arriving from the UK don't go through border control in any event, because of the common travel area.  Is this incorrect?  If it is correct then I don't see how the quoted material applies here.

Comment: @phoog It depends. Ireland to UK, I've never had to go through border control. However, UK to Ireland I've had to go through border control on every occasion (and I fly back and forth pretty regularly).

Comment: @phoog It is incorrect, flying TO Ireland you always clear border control.

Comment: I honestly doubt that this interpretation is correct, since OP is flying on two separate tickets. If the first flight is delayed, the second flight cancelled or any other circumstance arise, so that the transfer in Ireland fails, he will be stuck in Dublin without being entitled to any assistance from Ryanair and Ryanair likely held responsible for bringing him there without fulfilling immigration requirements.

Answer (score 2):

"Ryanair... said that I need to have my visa checked before going to security." Your visa will be checked by Ryanair before you board in Newcastle; the airline wants to ensure you have the correct travel documents for your final destination. Just show your Schengen visa and bordering card for the connecting flight.

Ryanair operates from Terminal 1 at Dublin Airport. Without checked luggage all you have to do is find your way to the departure gate in the same terminal. There is no need to go through the border control.